# Two divs float left, one float right in row

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to have 3 divs in one row. I've the code below and the biggest problem is, that second div doesn't end where third starts. The line also should be aligned vertically to center of texts. Result should look like this https://www.linksketch.com/XOfi
Texts in the first div may vary by length. So I can't specify it's width (or width of second one).

```css
.activityType {
    color: #007b87;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.lineActivities {
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #afbc16;
    opacity: .4;
    margin: 10px 10px 2px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.activityDate {
    color: #007b87;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<!-- First div with text aligned to left. -->
<div class="activityType">
    User created tiket
</div>

<!-- Second div with colored line going from 1. to 3. div (filling the gap). -->
<div class="lineActivities">
</div>

<!-- Third div with text. -->
<div class="activityDate">
    23. 02. 2015 01:31:33
</div>
```

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: the link you provided is asking for password...

Comment: Link should work now.

Comment: @SanjayaPandey: I tried playing with float, clear and overflow of all 3 divs. No success.
One way would be position line in layer under whole row and then position texts over it, but it seems to me like unclean solution.

Comment: your second div has width property (140px) that one will also be variable??

Comment: You probably mean third one (the date) and it won't change (although it would be nice, if it could :D ).
Second one (the line) has to reach from 1. to 3. div. Considering 1. div lenght will change, the line has change too.

Comment: @TomášČervenka pls see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without an intervening third div if you wrap them items into one div...then use a pseudo-element..like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.activity {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.activity:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: dotted 2px tomato;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.5em; /* controls position of line vertically */
}

.activityType {
  color: #007b87;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.activityDate {
  color: #007b87;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity">
  <p class="activityType">User created ticket</p>
  <p class="activityDate">23. 02. 2015 01:31:33</p>
</div>

<div class="activity">
  <p class="activityType">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p class="activityDate">23. 02. 2015 01:31:33</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to make the line not to be on bottom, but aligned vertically to center of text (of row)?

Answer (score 1):

I divided your left divs into a seperate div and gave the 2 divs the one total of 81% space. it should work now. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musLmLr9/1/)

```css
.activityType {
    color: #007b87;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.lineActivities {
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #afbc16;
    opacity: .4;
    margin: 10px 10px 2px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#right .activityDate {
    color: #007b87;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width:95%;
}
#left{overflow-x: hidden; width:81%;}
#left, #right{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id ="left"><div class="activityType">
    User created tiket
</div>

<!-- Second div with colored line going from 1. to 3. div (filling the gap). -->
<div class="lineActivities">
</div>
</div>
<div id ="right">
<!-- Third div with text. -->
<div class="activityDate">
    23. 02. 2015 01:31:33
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The point is, the texts in the firts div may vary by length. So I can't   specify any width (I'll add it to post).

Comment: @TomášČervenka then replace the percentages with "auto"

Comment: Doesn't make the trick. Then it results into same output as my original code.

Comment: This works too, thanks. Only problem is when scaling down screen size, instead of just shortening the line, date started to fold to another line. That's why I went with Paulie_D solution.

Answer (score 0):

if your third `div` width won't change, then you can achieve easily what you want with the following css applied to 2nd `div` (the line) -

`margin-right: 140px;`

make sure to increase the margin right to create a small gap between the line and the 3rd `div`.
http://jsfiddle.net/mc7d1Laj/1/

Comment: Nice and simple solution. One more thing - how to make the line not to be on top, but aligned vertically to center of text?

Comment: if you will set `line-height: 1px` on the 1st and 3rd `div` then the line will be aligned vertically middle.

Comment: I used Paulie_D solution but this one seems to work aswell. Thanks!

Comment: If I were at your place, I would have did the same.. because I think Paulie_D answer is the BEST..